# Use NSUserDefaults to keep a subview hidden

Tags: nsuserdefaults

i'm new to NSUserDefaults and have been having a hard time getting information about it... The thing is i'm trying to have a subview that'll ask the user for some data, but only the first time they open that subview, i was trying to make the 'ok' button the one that activates the boolean for the key... what i did was this

At .h file

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView* myView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* OK;
-(IBACtion)OK:(UIButton *)sender;
```

At .m in the viewDidLoad:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"OKButton"]){
self.myView.hidden=YES;
}
else{
self.myView.hidden=NO;
}
};
```

and then

```
-(IBAction)OK:(UIButton*)sender{
if(sender.tag==1){
self.myView.hidden=YES;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"OKButton"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]synchronize];
}
else{
self.myView.hidden=NO;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"OKButton"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]synchronize];
};
```

the problem is every time I click on the OK Button, the app crashes "terminate called throwing an exception... Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is the exactly exception?  empty/null pointer?

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance i think

Comment: so, that would be your problem, any warning on your Xcode editor? have a check....

Comment: nop... it says no issues... what exactly does that error mean??

Comment: Oh thanks! i've found it... it was all on the storyboard

Comment: solved the exceptions... but the button is not hiding the view

Comment: got it... the sender.tag should be ==0... thanks for the help!